# AWS Amplify with CDK

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, aws-cdk, aws-amplify

I have an AWS Amplify application using a handful of services (Auth, API, Analytics, etc). The app is designed to be turn key and users/data need to be isolated per user group. The other requirement is rapid scale-out so I've been looking into AWS CDK as a means to trigger new instances of the application.

After reviewing the documentation, it does look as if you can implement Amplify workflows through CDK, but what is not clear is whether you can retrieve a repo from Git, initialise Amplify with a set of provided values (app name, Cognito login types, etc).

The documentation is pretty vague but asking to see if anyone has been in this situation before?

Comment: you mean you need to deploy many Amplify apps? how many?

Comment: Could be any number of apps instantiated. The issue here is configuring each instance upon deployment. There's no complicated logic, just setting values.